# Increment list size based on elapsed time

Tags: python, time

I am creating a program that will measure the execution times of various sorting algorithms (Selection, Bubble, Merge, and Tree sort).

The list sizes used for the test cases should start at 10,000, and go up by 10,000 for each test until the execution time for the test exceeds 60 seconds.

And that is my issue.

I have this probably very wrong (and ugly) code that I have created (I am currently testing with just the Bubble Sort).

```
import random
import time

def bubbleSort(a_list):
    for passnum in range(len(a_list)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if a_list[i]>a_list[i+1]:
                temp = a_list[i]
                a_list[i] = a_list[i+1]
                a_list[i+1] = temp

a_list = []
for i in range(10000):
    a_list.append(random.randrange(0,10000))

start = time.perf_counter()    
bubbleSort(a_list)
end = time.perf_counter()

elapsed = end - start
print("{0:.8f}".format(elapsed, "\n"))    
print(a_list)

if elapsed <= 60:
    for i in range(len(a_list), len(a_list)+10000):
        a_list.append(random.randrange(len(a_list)+10000))

        start = time.perf_counter()    
        bubbleSort(a_list)
        end = time.perf_counter()

        elapsed = end - start
        print("{0:.8f}".format(elapsed, "\n"))    
        print(a_list)
else:
    #it'll quit
```

I'm sorry for the ignorance that is very apparent.
 So above was my first reaction. Then I came up with this loop:

```
start = time.perf_counter() 
while start <= 60:
    for i in range(len(a_list)+10000):
        a_list.append(random.randrange(len(a_list)+10000))    
        bubbleSort(a_list)

end = time.perf_counter()

elapsed = end - start
print("{0:.8f}".format(elapsed, "\n"))    
print(a_list)
```

I would be very grateful if someone can give me a push in the right direction and help me think of the logic behind it. Thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, collapse some of the code to improve readability:

- Element switch now uses the Python idiom `a, b = b, a`
- Build the list with a comprehension, not a loop
- parametrize the list size; increment each time through the loop.
- Do you *really* need 8 decimal places for the execution time?

Code:

```
import random
import time

def bubbleSort(a_list):
    for passnum in range(len(a_list)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if a_list[i] > a_list[i+1]:
                a_list[i], a_list[i+1] = a_list[i+1], a_list[i]

elapsed = 0
size = 0
size_inc = 10000

print("Size\tTime")
while elapsed < 60:
    # Add 10,000 numbers to the list
    size += size_inc
    a_list = [random.randrange(0,size) for i in range(size)]

    start = time.perf_counter()    
    bubbleSort(a_list)
    end = time.perf_counter()
    elapsed = end - start

    print(size, "\t{0:.8f}".format(elapsed, "sec.\n"))
```

Output:

```
Size    Time
10000   12.05934826
20000   47.99201040
30000   111.39582218
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is very clear to me.
And about the seconds thing, yes you're right I don't. I just copied the format from another program I had opened and didn't change the decimal places.
Have a good day/night!